# Display text (string) in the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, nstextview, outlet

I want to display some text (string) in a NSTextView Outlet in a storyboard file, but it does not work. I am not sure if I used the best approach. Is the selected method "insertText" the correct one? is the outlet connection correct? Does the storyboard support the NSTextView class?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : NSViewController
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *closerText;
@end

ViewController.c

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize closerText;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

[closerText insertText:@"Hello World"];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the NSTextView is connected to the closerText IBOutlet.  insertText is the correct function.